# Jquery plugins and Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to link a Jquery plugin from application.html.erb. The plugin code is in Asset/js like a picture show:

[image: javascript]

How a can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can include it via `javascript_include_tag` in `application.html.erb`

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'typed' %>
```

**or**

you can modify your `application.js` to include the below code

```
//= require typed
```

Comment: No work. Typed is a folder. Inside the folder is another folder called js. And inside this folder we can find typed.js. How can I link the file??

Comment: @ildefonsoarevalo Try `//= require typed/js/typed`